# Is a dictionary turing complete

Tags: turing-machines, turing-complete

With "dictionary" I mean an array of key / value pairs with unique keys. If not, why? If long enough, you can use the key as an input and the value as an output and it could have the solution to as many problems as you wish. It could "compute" anything as long as it's long enough to hold every possible input. Which wouldn't need be infinite as long as is established that the input will have a certain amount of bits. So if we agree that the input will be X bits, then you will only need a dictionary with 2^X items and you have every possible turing machine that will take X bits as an input.

Right? Well I guess I'm not but why?

Comment: Thats like saying a hard drive is Turing complete.

Comment: @soandos: it's more like saying a CD-ROM is Turing-complete.

Comment: Or like saying a piece of paper is turing complete. But still what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @Beta: I think its more like a hard drive, as the symbols can be rewritten.

Comment: Well, leaving aside the problem of the dictionary entry for a non-halting machine, there's simply the fact that a Turing machine doesn't have a limit in the size of its input.

Comment: @soandos: Eh? The symbols in a dictionary cannot be rewritten.

Comment: "...The machine can alter the scanned symbol" from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine

Comment: @soandos: excuse me, but your logic is flawed. The symbols in a dictionary cannot be rewritten, so a dictionary is more like a CD-ROM than like a hard drive. A Turing machine is more like a hard drive than like a CD-ROM, but the OP is not asking whether a Turing machine is Turing-complete.

Comment: @beta: Sorry, I was confused. I was talking about the symbols on a turing machine, not the dictionary.

Comment: @jsoldi: in the original post, you said it could "compute." how?

Comment: Could this be as simple as "Yes. See dynamic programming/memoization"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple Turing machine can add two integers-- *any* two integers. A finite dictionary cannot.

**EDIT:**
(I'm editing my answer because soandos made a point too good to answer in a cramped comment box.)

Good Question! Suppose we have an infinite dictionary, listing {key, value} pairs where the keys are all possible combinations of Turing machines and their finite inputs (or equivalently, all possible finite input sequences to a universal Turing machine), in order of increasing size. The values are the corresponding final states, with a leading bit to indicate [HALTS, DOES NOT HALT]. I argue that this *is* Turing-complete. (The act of looking up an entry is trivially simple and I don't think we have to argue about it).

The unsolvability of the Halting Problem has an equivalent in JSoldi's Dictionary: if we want to be able to look up the [HALT, DOES NOT HALT] bit of any entry below a certain size, we need only a finite part of the dictionary. But to implement that much of the dictionary as a Turing machine, we would need a machine larger than that limiting size-- it's entry would not be in that portion of the dictionary. For any size of machine there is a machine that can answer the Halting Question for all machines of that size-- but *that* machine is bigger, so it can't answer the question about itself. Likewise any finite volume of the dictionary is completely repeated in an entry somewhere (in fact, infinitely many entries), but that entry is not in that volume.

Comment: This is kinda what I was thinking. Maybe I'm thinking too much like a programmer and too little like a mathematician. But I don't know strictly or formally what's that. I guess I should just read more about it.

Comment: The point is not really the size limitation though. It is like you are comparing a struct and a processor...

Comment: Well on that case all you need is add a scanner that goes through all the keys until it finds the required one and outputs the value and it would be the simplest turing machine ever. I think it does have something to do with the input not having a size limit.

Comment: @jsoldi: adding the scanner makes the dictionary no longer a dictionary. Adding scanners and values and outputs makes it less and less like a dictionary and more and more like a proper Turing machine.

Comment: You need something that can execute instructions/symbols. A dictionary just sits there.

Comment: @whatsisname: Is just a scanner I just didn't say it in my question because is kinda assumed. If a turing machine could be reduced to a dictionary with a scanner whose ONLY job is to find a key that is equal to the input then I don't know why didn't Turing came up with this way simpler idea. I really think that's NOT why a dictionary is not turing complete.

Comment: @soandos: I think I see your point, but if we limit the size of the input (and the machine) then we *can* make a dictionary of all possible machines and input sequences, so in that sense it is limited-Turing-complete. What matters is the final result (if any), not how we get to it.

Comment: @beta: then how does any infinitely sized medium not count as a Turing machine? (or are you saying it does)

Comment: @beta: I'll go a step farther, and say that the decimal representation of pi is Turing complete. every sequence of numbers is represented.

Comment: @sonados: For what I understand I think a turing machine doesn't need to get bigger as the input get bigger. A dictionary does.

Comment: @jsoldi: a turing machine always has "...an infinite memory capacity" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine that is not the issue. The question that seems to be being asked is: Is that property, and holding all possible data states enough, or does it also need: " theoretical device that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules" same link

Comment: I don't think it needs to operate to be turing complete as long as it can return the same results as a turing machine can. The problem with my dictionary, I believe, is in the fact that to perform a simple addition between any two integers you would always need an infinite dictionary.

Comment: no, the problem with your dictionary is it cant add. it cant compute. it cant do anything but sit there. a turing machine is more than a storage device (that is infinite in size, see link) its a machine. it uses a table of rules, takes input, and does stuff. a dictionary sits there. It is not a machine in any sense of the word.

Comment: OK then add the scanner. If the scanner makes it a turing machine (and remember ALL this scanner does is find the key that is equal to the input and output the value) wouldn't this be the simplest turing machine ever?

Comment: great. so now you have a tape that runs back and forth, and never writes and data. for example to "add" what is in the scanner, it looks at what is there, then goes somewhere else, and looks at that, then moves. how would it add 1+2 if those were the first two entries?

Comment: @beta: the set of irrationals is uncountable infinite. how could the machine get from the entry containing 1 to the entry containing 2?
Even if it could, how would it perform addition? merely looking up a value does not help, i dont think... Also, one could argue that a dictionary cheats, as there are really TWO symbols in the scanner at a time.

Comment: No no, the "1+2" would be written somewhere as a key already. It wouldn't need to go anywhere else, just to the "1+2" key, which would have "3" as value. You would have a huge list of possible operations. That's why you would need a limited size input (say, limited amount of character). For instance, I could easily write in Notepad a dictionary with all possible operations that can be written with 3 characters or less.

Comment: @soandos: it would look up those two values in the (complete, endless) addition table, and there it would stop. Changing symbols is (part of) how a Turing machine works, but we can come up with some other logical system that is equivalent, and therefore Turing-complete, but doesn't change symbols.

Comment: @soandos: oh come on, irrationals? I can get all of the rational numbers into a dictionary, but I'm not stupid enough to try to list them in order of size. And can list all of the irrationals *that can be written out by finite Turing machines*, but that's not all of the irrationals.

Comment: @Beta: So are you saying it IS turing complete? How about the unlimited size of the input in a turing machine?

Comment: @beta @jsoldi should we open a new thread on the nature of turing machines?

Comment: @beta, then you cant list any of them... (there is no such thing as a finite irrational...)

Comment: @soandos: I can list countably infinitely many of them, including all the computable ones. And yes, I am saying that the infinite dictionary is Turing-complete (although not pi, since as far as I know pi is not organized that way).

Answer (score 0):

A Turing machine would be able to compute any kind of input with any kind of program, and it doesn't have to be fixed length input. A dictionary furthermore would have no way of selecting which key/value pair matches the input for a selected program.

Additionally, if you have an input of X bits, your key space won't be X^2, it will be 2^X. And that will be for a single program.

In fact, even if you had a dictionary with infinitely many key/value pairs, I bet the logic required to determine which key you had to select, would probably require a Turing machine or something more complicated to select the key.

Comment: "A dictionary furthermore would have no way of selecting which key/value pair matches the input for a selected program" The dictionary IS the program here. You are right I meant 2^X. But I don't think you need a turing machine to determine which key you want. You just want the key that is equal to the input.

Comment: A turing machine is programmable. If it's fixed with a single program, it's not a turing machine anymore. If its a fixed program it is essentially a finite state machine, which is not the same thing. Turing machines have both the Tape and the Action Table as inputs.

Comment: Sorry I meant, the content of the dictionary would be the program (which you could theoretically edit). And the way to find which input matches a key/value pair would be by simply finding the key that is equal to the input. The output is the value.

Comment: I'd say it differently. True, a dictionary can't choose an entry to look up in itself, but then a Turing machine can't choose what program it runs.

Answer (score -1):

Turing completeness has to do with a set of rules to do something, not how data is stored. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).